# QR code image not showing after downloading

Tags: jquery

[image]

I have QR code image with one more image in the same div when i take a screenshot of that div or downloading that image the QR code is not showing their..

Here is my code

html

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="qrdiv">
                            <div class="bg-white mt-4 p-4 text-center">
                                <img style="width :100%" id="img1" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/mobile.JPEG') }}" alt="">

                                <div class="inner-div">
                                @if(Auth::user()->shop->qr_request != 'Approved')
                                    <a href="#" onclick="update_req()" class="btn btn-styled btn-base-1 qr-re-btn btn-outline btn-sm">Order QR Code</a>
                                @else
                                     <p>
                                        <img id="qr-code" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=%3A%2F%2F{{ route('shop.visit', Auth::user()->shop->slug) }}%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Your Profile" />
                                        <br />
                                    </p>
                               @endif
                                </div>
                                @if(Auth::user()->shop->qr_request == 'Approved')
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" id="download_qr_btn" class="btn btn-styled btn-base-1 btn-outline btn-sm">Download Now</a>
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var element = $("#qrdiv"); 
var getCanvas; 

html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        getCanvas = canvas;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have two images one is QR image and other one is their template image
when i download it only template image was showing not the QR image

Comment: add your comment in question.